# How to implement this complex query in ORM style in Django?

Tags: django

I have a complex query that help me create a rich data set to display in a list view. The result of the query includes fields from Event model and a field based on the aggregation in the subquery.

I'd like to know how to implement this using Django ORM instead of writing raw queries all the time?

Sample query below:

```
SELECT g.event_id,event_name, gm.member_counts 
    from care_event g 
    inner join (
      SELECT gc.event_id, COUNT(DISTINCT gc.member_id) AS member_counts FROM event_member gc
      INNER JOIN care_member m on gc.member_id = m.member_id and m.is_deleted = 'N'
      GROUP BY 1
    ) gm ON g.event_id = gm.event_id

    WHERE org_id = %(org_id)s AND g.is_deleted = 'N'
```

Event, Member and EventMember are models that store data.

[**Update**] Mode code added below:

```
class Member(models.Model):

    member_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'care_member'


class Event(models.Model):

    event_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    org_id = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='EventMember')
    is_deleted = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='N', null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'care_event'


class EventMember(models.Model):

    # DB auto generated 'id' field is the PK.
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member_id = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event_member'
```

Can I have a conceptual level implementation of this query in ORM style? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look at this page for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Your question is hard to answer without knowing your models since JOINTS are influenced by the model definition and not so much by your ORM query.